# Remove/replace space from value of div ID

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

I have a manufacturer directory page, each manufacturer div ID is dynamically populated by the brand name. The goal is to allow manufacturers to share their link with their customers (ex:https://libraries.specifiglobal.com/partners/request-foodservice-equipment-libraries/#angel-po)

Obviously this isn't perfect since names often include spaces and/or an apostrophe. The functionality I am trying to achieve  is to ideally replace spaces with dashes and remove the apostrophe altogether.

I have tried the code below, however it changes all div ID's to the first manufacturer in a list.

```
var myText = jQuery('.card-header').closest(".w-100").attr("id");
var newMyText = myText.replace(/ /g,'-');

// remove older id and place new id
jQuery('.card-header').closest(".w-100").attr("id", newMyText);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('.card-header')
    .closest(".w-100")
    .each(function() {
        e = jQuery(this);
        e.attr('id', e.attr('id').replace(/ /g,'-'));
    });
```

Comment: thank you that worked. How do I replace /./ and / - / as well? here is what i tried.
```jQuery('.card-header')
    .closest(".w-100")
    .each(function() {
        e = jQuery(this);
        e.attr('id', e.attr('id').replace(/ /g,'-').replace(/ - /g,'-').replace(/./g,''));
    });
```

Comment: @jl312 try `.replace(/[.-\s]/g, '')`